# Updating table in html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have been attempting to update a table, which is meant to be a "shopping cart."  However, upon pressing the "add to cart button", my table does not update.

The html for the javascript just uses getElementbyId, and both tables appear on the screen when I run the html file.

I'm still fairly new to javascript, so I was hoping someone with more experience could double check for me to see that I have what I need.

```
var html = "<table border = '1|1' >";

html += "<td>Product Name</td>";
html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
html += "<td>Price</td>";
html += "<td>Add to Cart</td>";

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i ++) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_name + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + <button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart(products[i].product_name, this)'>Add to Cart</button> + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";

}

html += "</table>";

document.getElementById("location1").innerHTML = html;


function addCart(product_id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            var cartItem = null;
            for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                    cartItem = cart[k];
                    cart[k].product_qty++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cartItem == null) {
                var cartItem = {
                    product: products[i],
                    product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                };
                cart.push(cartItem);
            }
        }
    }
    renderCartTable();

}

//RenderCartTable & its functions
function addCart(product_id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            var cartItem = null;
            for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                    cartItem = cart[k];
                    cart[k].product_qty++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cartItem == null) {

                cartItem = {
                    product: products[i],
                    product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                };
                cart.push(cartItem);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code pulls from a list of products, and produces a table with the name, description, and price of the item, along with the Add to Cart button.  The button is meant to add the item to a different list, called "cart".
Any and all help appreciated.  Thanks for your time!

Below is all of the code--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <p id="location1"> </p>
        <br/>
        <h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
        <p id="location2"> </p>
        <h2>Grand Total:</h2>
        <p id="location3"> </p>


        <script type="text/javascript", language="javascript", src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
            var products = [];
            var cart = [];

            //label individual products below in individual lists, and then have the product put through the product_setup function
            var product1 = ["Anvil", "Premium Grade Iron", 119.99];
            var product2 = ["Female Roadrunner Costume", "Guaranteed to attract Male Roadrunners", 54.99];

            function product_setup(product) {
                var productID = product[0];
                var product_desc = product[1];
                var qty = 1;
                var price = product[2];

                var newProduct = {
                    product_id: null,
                    product_desc: null,
                    product_qty: 0,
                    product_price: 0.00,
                };
                newProduct.product_id = productID;
                newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
                newProduct.product_qty = qty;
                newProduct.product_price = price;


                products.push(newProduct);
            }

            product_setup(product1);
            product_setup(product2);    


            function product_table() {
                var html = "<table border = '1|1' >";

                html += "<td>Product Name</td>";
                html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
                html += "<td>Price</td>";
                html += "<td> </td>";


                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i ++) {
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_id + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + "<button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart(products[i].product_id, this)'>Add to Cart</button>" + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                }

                html += "</table>";

                document.getElementById("location1").innerHTML = html;
            }
            product_table();

            function subtractQuantity(product_id) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                    if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                        cart[i].product_qty--;
                    }

                    if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                        cart.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
                renderCartTable();
            }

            function addQuantity(product_id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                    if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                        cart[i].product_qty++;
                    }  
                }
                renderCartTable();
            }

            function removeItem(product_id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                    if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                        cart.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
                renderCartTable();
            }

            function renderCartTable() {
                var html = '';
                var ele = document.getElementById("location2");
                ele.innerHTML = ''; 

                html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
                html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
                html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
                html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
                html += "<td>Price</td>";
                html += "<td>Total</td>";
                html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
                var GrandTotal = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty, 10) + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick= 'subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'>Subtract Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Item</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='removeItem(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Remove Item</button></td>";
                    html += "</tr>";

                    GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty, 10);
                }

                document.getElementById("location3").innerHTML = "$ " + GrandTotal;
                html += "</table>";
                ele.innerHTML = html;
            }
            renderCartTable();

            function addCart(product_id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                        var cartItem = null;
                        for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                            if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                                cartItem = cart[k];
                                cart[k].product_qty++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (cartItem == null) {

                            cartItem = {
                                product: products[i],
                                product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                            };
                            cart.push(cartItem);

                        }
                    }
                }
                renderCartTable();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add enough code so we can run this. Don't need any style. Just basic html and where `renderCartTable` is declared etc

Comment: What I'm guessing is the the `renderCartTable` code, `var html = ...<snip>... innerHTML = html` is not inside a function? If that is not the actual `renderCartTable(){...}`, would you mind showing it to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
html += "<td>" + "<button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\")'>Add to Cart</button>" + "</td>";
```

In your case, when clicking the button `onclick = 'addCart(products[i].product_id)`, The `i` inside `products[i]` is only known inside the `product_table(){...}` so when called outside it's context, `i` is undefined. There was an attempt to pass the context in using `this`, while a good idea, that `i` would be knows inside `addCart` and not where addCart is being called (global context, or window) and since the for-loop continues that `i` would not have the correct value.

So instead we pass the whole product-id in as a string and it works.

#### So how could we get rid of the ugly escape-strings?

Template literals are almost always prettier   `` html += `<td><button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart("${products[i].product_id}")'>Add to Cart</button></td>`; `` but it's a ES6 feature (so check what browsers you need to support).

I think binding the click-event to the container, and outside the renderfunction would be prettier. Since we only need one listener that way. As opposed to creating new onclicks on every call to `renderCartTable`.

```
var clickHandler = function(evt){
    if(evt.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
      // Check that we have the right button (from a class perhaps)
      // parse out data from event.target.parentElement
      // or pass in product-id via a data attribute
    }
};
document.getElementById("location1").addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are passing `product_name` to the addCart and checking it against `product_id`.

Try putting `debugger;` and check the value you get in the function.

Answer (score -1):

try this, hope this works:

```
var html = "<table border = '1|1' >";
html += "<td>Product Name</td>";
html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
html += "<td>Price</td>";
html += "<td>Add to Cart</td>";

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i ++) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_name + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + "<button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart("+products[i].product_id+", this)'>Add to Cart</button>" + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";

document.getElementById("location1").innerHTML = html;

function addCart(product_id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            var cartItem = null, cartItemId;
            if (cart.length > 0)
                for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                    if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                        cartItem = cart[k];
                        cart[k].product_qty++;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            if (cartItem == null) {
                var cartItem = {
                    product: products[i],
                    product_qty: products[i].product_qty  + 1
                };
                cartItemId = cart.push(cartItem);
            }
        }
    }
    renderCartTable();
}
```

also make sure **products** array looks like this:

```
var products = [
    {product_id: 0, product_name: "item1", product_desc: "desc1", product_price: 100, product_qty: 0},
    {product_id: 1, product_name: "item2", product_desc: "desc2", product_price: 200, product_qty: 0},
    {product_id: 2, product_name: "item3", product_desc: "desc3", product_price: 300, product_qty: 0},
    {product_id: 3, product_name: "item4", product_desc: "desc4", product_price: 400, product_qty: 0}
];
```

Answer (score -2):

functions wont work on appended data, so better use JQuery or something and do it like this.

```
  $('#myTable').on('click','.addToCart',function(){
         //perform something...
  });
```

You can also do

```
  $(document).on('click','.addToCart',function(){
         //perform something...
  });
```

Comment: First statement is just not true

Comment: In his case his table is also appended, so he better use the 2nd one, but in my case i already created the table in html, and put ID and just append data there so I use the first one always

Comment: That last comment has nothing to do with what OP is doing or asking and this question is not tagged jQuery